# Reverse engineering random camera module from mobile devices

Tags: datasheet, pinout, information

I have A camera module I believe either from a tablet or a cell phone and I want to know where to find information on the serial pin out or on how to read the ribbon of the camera[image: camera module]

Comment: what is preventing you from searching for the information?

Answer (score 1):

That camera uses the Sony IMX219 1/4" 8 megapixel cmos image sensor. It's the same sensor that is used in the Arducam IMX219 for wich there is plenty of data available. It's hard to say if the connector follows any conventions but you may be able to figure it out once you have some info on the sensor. [Arducam Page](https://www.arducam.com/product/arducam-imx219-auto-focus-camera-module-drop-in-replacement-for-raspberry-pi-v2-and-nvidia-jetson-nano-camera/)

[Sony Datasheet from Arducam Site](https://www.arducam.com/downloads/modules/RaspberryPi_camera/IMX219DS.PDF)